# Finding a path on a coordinate plane

Tags: sequences-and-series, contest-math

> On a coordinate plane, a path consists of a series of moves in the positive $x$- or $y$- direction. If the first move is 1 unit in length, the second move is 2 units, the third move is 3 units, and so on, how many such paths exist that start at the origin and end at $(14,14)$?

Okay, to be honest, I'm not sure how to tackle this problem at all. I do know (or at least I think) there'll be 7 moves total as $1+2+3+4+5+6+7=28$ and $14 \times 2 =28$. 
But then afterwards I got stuck again and tried labeling all columns $a,b,c,d$... and all horizontal lines $1,2,3,4$..., but that didn't seem to work either because I don't think that's what the problem's really asking for.

How would you solve this?

The answer is $8$ paths.

Answer (score 2):

You are corect that it takes exactly 7 moves. The nth move increases x or y, but not both, by the amount n. We have 14=7+6+1=7+5+2=7+4+3=7+4+2+1. If the 7th move increases x this gives 4 paths, and if the 7th move increases y this gives 4 more. Total 8 paths. Example: x increases at the 1st, 2nd, 4th, & 7th moves while y increases at the other moves.